# Cell value in Header - different for each worksheet and macro to loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have reports that I work on each month and have to change the headers. I have 20 worksheets in the workbook, and each worksheet needs to have different headers.

I wanted to create a macro for header, that would reference to 4 cells in each worksheet.

eg - worksheet one - Q115 vs Q414 - Header needs to reference cell a150,a151,a152,a153. The cell a152 has a formula in it. FY15 vs FY14 worksheet would refer to cells a150,a151,a152,a153 within itself, so on ... I created a macro after googling but once I run it all the worksheets have the header from the first active worksheet.

Can you please help me correct it?

```
Sub InsertHeaderFooter()

Dim sheetIndex, numsheets As Integer
sheetIndex = 1
numsheets = Sheets.Count
' Loop through each sheet, but don't set any of them to active
While sheetIndex <= numsheets
    Dim sheetname, role, labeltext As String
    sheetname = Sheets(sheetIndex).name
    role = GetRole(mode) 
    labeltext = "Some text - " & sheetname & " - " & role
 strong text        
    With Sheets(sheetIndex).PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = vbCr & Range("A150").Text & vbCr & Range("A151").Text & _
            vbCr & Range("A152").Text & vbCr & Range("A153").Text
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = "SanDisk Confidential"
        .RightFooter = "&[Date] - &[Time]"
    End With
    sheetIndex = sheetIndex + 1
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Your posted code doesn't align with your question. Please illustrate what you want to achieve (provide screen shots and links) and provide the code you use which fails.

Comment: Hello, I apologize but I am new to vba .. why do you think they dont sink ?

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
.CenterHeader = vbCr & Range("A150").Text & vbCr & Range("A151").Text & _
            vbCr & Range("A152").Text & vbCr & Range("A153").Text
```

to

```
  .CenterHeader = vbCr & .Range("A150").Text & vbCr & .Range("A151").Text & _
        vbCr & .Range("A152").Text & vbCr & .Range("A153").Text
```

`Range` makes a reference to the active sheet.

`.Range` makes a reference to the `With Sheets(sheetIndex)` sheet.

Comment: Hello thank you for trying to help .. I tried putting the above the change but it says the object/Method is not supported ?

Comment: What object/method does it say is not supported? I see two potential problems in your code... one is `GetRole(mode)` if you don't have a function or sub named `GetRole`. The other is `strong text`. Not sure at all what that is supposed to be doing.